# How are SEOs done for dynamic websites? Whether each page is separately built static?

Tags: html, css, search, seo, search-engine

I had a food takeaway website where the users can search the restaurants by giving their area name. I want my website's `LONDON` search page to be listed when user searches in Google `TAKEAWAYS IN LONDON`.

I think google doesn't crawl websites with query string. How can we achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that Google just looks at the page you create, not *how* you create it.

Now this basically translates your question to "how do we make our dynamic pages visible to Google"? There are a number of tricks. Basically you build links from your homepage to specific other pages. You could have a "Top 5 searches" box, with links to "http://www.example.com/london/takeaways" etc. On the result pages, you can have links to similar queries, e.g. "http://www.example.com/london/finedining".

Basically, Google will see and follow those links, and remember the results per URL. The basic SEO rules till apply - good content, clear structure, etc. Don't bother Google or users with query strings. Use URL rewriting if a query string easier for you internally.

Comment: Wow! thanks for taking time for clearing my doubts. So I had to two things, 1. Implement URL Rewriting    2.  Giving Links for important cities in homepage and in other pages.

But While saying that another doubt arises. If a city is unpopular say a village, in which that link is not given in homepage, then how the search for that city will be listed??

Comment: The world wide web is called a web for a reason. Any page which isn't reachable via a link doesn't belong to the web. Since you can't rely on others, you must provide those links yourself. That's why I suggested the "similar results" page. You'd link that small village from a nearby larger town.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're supposed to have a sitemap, which could have a discoverable link to a page of yours whose URL is `http://www.food.com/london` and whose title and heading is 'TAKEAWAYS IN LONDON' (and whose contents you can retrieve dynamically).

Comment: Can i have title tag like this for search page <title>Takeaways in <? echo $q; ?> </title>?

Comment: @Rajasekar I don't know: what is `$q;`?

Comment: Its a variable. Simply it prints the search term in that location. So if q is london then the title is TAKEAWAYS IN LONDON